# How to use js var inside or <p> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this problem:

```
function x() {  
    selectedsystem=document.getElementById("targetSystem").value;
    selectedversion=document.getElementById("targetVersion").value;
}
```

I have to call the `selectedsystem`:

```
if(issystemidle == TRUE)
    {
    var main_content_xml = "<p>System " selectedsystem " is idle </p>"; 
    }
```

Do I have to use `+ var +`  or `smth`?

Comment: *do i have to use + var + or smth?* - Yes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can concate it using `+`

```
if (issystemidle) {
  var main_content_xml = "<p>System " + selectedsystem + " is idle </p>";
}
```

Else use template literals

```
if (issystemidle) {
  var main_content_xml = `<p>System ${selectedsystem} is idle </p>`;
}
```

Also you can do `if(issystemidle){}` instead of `if(issystemidle == TRUE)`